# Crystal reports no data lable

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report containing some sub reports and in my main report i am showing the sub reports based on scan mode and status coming from query.

Now i need to show  a message whenever sub reports don't have data.

I tried like this.

checked supress blank sub report and supress blank section for all reports.

1.Kept a text box in report footer of main report.
2.Took a field (Say Barcode) from sub report and passed to main report using shared variable.
3.In section expert of text box wrote like this.

not isnull(Barcode)

But it is not working.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood this correctly the code below should work. Tip, avoid using NOT ISNULL. If possible just change the outcome order of your IF statement as below.

To make your formula more robust also, it's a great idea to add in the:

```
OR = ""
```

To account for any blank entries.

Final code:

```
 IF Isnull({Barcode}) OR {Barcode} = "" THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE
```

Comment: Excellent! Good to hear. Please accept if it worked perfect. :)